# Visual Studio 2015 - Remove blue highlight over variable name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Trying to remove the annoying highlight feature of Visual Studios. Found some references to C#, and searched around the settings, but I haven't found out how to disable it for C++.

This feature is driving me nuts. Please help me save my sanity!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> c++ -> Advanced ->
References -> Disable reference highlighting.

That should do it for you.